# I cannot change the array in State

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I can't pass the codes here properly. So I will explain this problem with pictures.
*(**NOTE**: These are all in the same component)*

**Problem:** 
I have one state value:

```
  state = {
    base: [ {tomato: false}, {egg: true} ],
    contents: [
      {mushroom: false},
      {olive: false},
      {greenPepper: false},
      {sausage: false},
      {tomato: false},
      {redPapper: false}
    ],
    selectBase: "tomato"
  };
```

---

There are six buttons in total. Each button is equal to a value in the "contents" array. In this way:

---

```
<label>
    <Checkbox checked={this.state.contents.olive} onChange= 
      {this.handleChanges('olive')} color="default" value="olive"/>Olive
</label>
// There are 5 more similar buttons.
```

---

This function works when I press the button:

---

```
  handleChanges = name => event => {
    this.setState({ 
      ...this.state,
      contents: [
        ...this.state.contents,
        {[name]: event.target.checked}
      ]
       });
      console.log(this.state)
  };
```

---

When I press the button, I want the value reached within the array to change. But instead it adds the same value to the array again.

---

[image]

---

My goal is just to change the value reached within the array. Other than that, they all need to remain constant. How can I do that?

---

**For all codes:**https://codepen.io/guldus/pen/MMeZqO?editors=1010

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: I can't pass the codes here properly.

Comment: Why can you not?

Comment: this is because you use method like a **push** method of an array. Correct way is find element in array and change this value.

Comment: @mr_alex No, React's state objects have to be initialized once and updated using setState

Comment: Paste the code -> select it -> click on `{}` icon in the editor

Comment: Have a look on a code more attentively please.

`var array = [...]
var newArray = [
   ...array,
   { a: {...} }
]`; This will push new value

Comment: afaik, setState only changes properties it is given and doesn't touch anything else. You can remove `...this.state,` from the passed object, for performance

Comment: @VLAZ I added it as code.

Comment: you don't even need to pass a name to your function you can just pass the index of the item and toggle the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you add a new object in `handleChanges`

```
handleChanges = name => event => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    contents: [
      ...this.state.contents,
      {[name]: event.target.checked} <-- Here you add a new object to the contents array 
    ]
  })
}
```

What you need to do is to find the element in the array and update it

```
handleChanges = name => event => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    // here we check if the current obj that we iterate on has the name field in it
    // if it does we replace it with a new object with the name
    // as the key and the new checked value
    contents: prevState.contents
      .map(obj => name in obj ? {[name]: event.target.checked} : obj)
  }))
}
```

Comment: pass a function to setState if current value, uses a value in state. `this.setState((prevState) => {} )`

Comment: @JuniusL. My answer doesn't depend on the current value unlike your answer where you toggle it based on the previous value so don't you think its unnecessary in this situation?

Comment: `contents: this.state.contents`

Comment: @JuniusL. Do you mean if multiple updates to contents queue and somehow one takes longer then the other the contents can get override through the map function am i understanding correct?

Comment: like https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate

Answer (score 0):

You cant see changed state after `setState`, becouse `setState` it's async method, if you want see result of `setState`, you need use callback:

```
setState(
  { field: "someValue" },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Answer (score 0):

You should find an object and then change its value.

```
handleChanges = name => event => {
   this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      contents: [
         ...this.state.contents,
         {  } // like a pushing new object. This is a problem
      ]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass index to your function as second parameter.

```
handleChanges = (name, index) => {

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    contents: [
      ...prevState.contents.slice(0, index),
      Object.assign({}, prevState.contents[index], { [name] : !prevState.contents[name]},
        ...prevState.contents.slice(index + 1))
    ]
  }));
}
```

And use it like

```
const checkboxes = this.state.contents.map((checkbox, index) => (
  <label>
    <Checkbox key={index} checked={this.state.contents[checkbox]} onChange=
      {() => this.handleChanges(checkbox, index)} color="default" value={checkbox} />{checkbox}
  </label>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Better use state update function if you're accessing state within the update

   ```
   this.setState((state, props) => ({
       counter: state.counter + props.increment
   }));
   ```

   2. You need to update the exact value, so your update will look this way:

      ```
      contents: ...state.contents.map(content => {

          if (content.hasOwnProperty(name) {
              return {[name]: event.target.checked}
          }
          return content;
      });
      ```